# Camera Rotation based on Keydown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am really really new to Unity and C# and i was just trying out some things. Now i want to kinda polish the overall control experience. So i want the Camera to rotate 5° on the Z axis when the Button A is pressed.

Thats what i tried:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if (zRotation < 5f)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(zRotation, 5f, 5f);
        }
    }
```

It somewhat works, the camera rotates to 5° on the Z but only for i split second and then returns to it's normal state.

Full Code of the Camera Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

public Transform playerBody;

float xRotation = 0f;
float zRotation = 0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        if (zRotation < 5f)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(zRotation, 5f, 5f);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you add the missing code? we can't see how you modify the value of `zRotation`

Comment: oRoiDev yep added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the Camera to rotate 5° on the Z axis when the Button A is pressed.

You don't need any variables to achieve this, it should be as simple as:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        cameraTransform.Rotate(0, 0, 5);
    }     
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i also noticed shortly after i asked the question but now there's the problem, that the camera only rotates for one frame and then snaps back into place.

Comment: @Zuckerpapa another part of your code must be overriding the z rotation of the camera, try debugging or commenting any lines that alter it's transform